# How to make a graphics with a point of intersection

Tags: plotting, graphics, splines

This is current method can do this

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    l1[t] = BezierFunction[
       temp1 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]][t]], {t, 0, 
    1}];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    l2[t] = BezierFunction[
       temp2 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]][t]], {t, 0, 
    1}];
Show[plot1, plot2, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> CoordinateBounds[Join[temp1, temp2], Scaled[1/5]]]
```

[image: img]

But this code cann't guarantee the existence of that point of intersection,sometime it'll give a result like this

[image: img]

So how to ensure **at least** one intersection in this graphics?

Comment: I don't think you can  "guarantee" that while playing with random numbers. What you can do is start from the intersection and then generate other points or insert a predefined intersection point in both `temp1` and `temp2`.

Comment: @Sumit Sounds a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to force `temp1` and `temp2` to share an endpoint:

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[l1[t] = BezierFunction[
       temp1 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]][t]], {t, 0, 3}];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[l2[t] = BezierFunction[
       temp2 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]; 
       temp2[[1]] = temp1[[1]]; temp2][t]], {t, 0, 3},  PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plot1, plot2, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange ->( Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ Transpose[Join[temp1, temp2]])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Another possibility would be to ensure that at least one point of one curve is within the convex hull of the control points of the other curve.

Comment: @J.M. good point. I thought that would work and would give richer configurations. However,  it is not sufficient to guarantee intersection of the curves.

Comment: Yes, it might fail every so often, but it is still more likely to succeed than blindly picking points in the plane.

Comment: I have change a little your code to want to share a middle point.But it cannot work every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment to @kglr with picture.I change his `temp2[[1]]=temp1[[1]]`to `temp2[[2]]=temp1[[2]];temp2[[3]]=Mean@Delete[temp1,2]`.But this method don't sufficient to guarantee intersection of the curves like

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    l1[t] = BezierFunction[
       temp1 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]][t]], {t, 0, 
    3}];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    l2[t] = BezierFunction[
       temp2 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}];
       temp2[[2]] = temp1[[2]]; temp2[[3]] = Mean@Delete[temp1, 2]; 
       temp2][t]], {t, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plot1, plot2, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> CoordinateBounds[Join[temp1, temp2], Scaled[1/5]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it'll work well in normally.Such as we can get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

And an another force method come to my mind with `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``.It can work fine,but there are some other smarter method must exist I think.

```
Label[begin]; plot1 = 
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[l1[t] = 
    BezierFunction[temp1 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]][
     t]], {t, 0, 1}]; plot2 = 
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[l2[t] = 
    BezierFunction[temp2 = RandomReal[{0, RandomReal[50]}, {3, 2}]][
     t]], {t, 0, 1}]; If[
 Length[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Show[plot1, plot2]]] >= 1, 
 Show[plot1, plot2, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> CoordinateBounds[Join[temp1, temp2], Scaled[1/5]]], 
 Goto[begin]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]